# How to create multiple sheets from a list of names which are the selected cells' content

Tags: excel, vba

Actually, I only need to help to provide some lessons on Excel VBA not for the code.

**Problem**:

[image]

The main line of code is very basic and although I have no experience in VBA, I understand it

```
Sheets.Add().Name = Name_of_Sheet
```

If I define a list of name like `NameList =Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC","SheetD")` then do the for loop

```
 For I = LBound(NameList) To UBound(NameList) 
    Sheets.Add().Name = Tabs(I) 
 Next I
```

However, many times, there are standard for naming the sheets, going to Visual Basic to edit the macro is not very efficient.  I would like to just create the sheet from the cells' content

**My questions**:

1) How does the index of selected data (1D columns, 1D row, or multiple rows x multiple columns) work?

2) How can I access these cells' content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite open-ended.  Here's a start that addresses the "1D Columns" aspect.  There are many ways to do this, but I've included a couple of basic VBA constructs, like `For Each` and `With/End With`.  You could easily point the variables at other workbooks, worksheets or cells.  It's got a little error-handling to address trying use a sheet name that already exists:

```
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A2:A5")
    With wbToAddSheetsTo
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next cell
End Sub
```

Another approach would be to load the cell contents into an array, which might be useful if it was in fact two-dimensional (and if there were tons of names) but it might also be overkill.

Comment: + 1 Doug :). However, I would recommend checking if the sheet exists and then creating the sheet and using `ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value`. `OERN` can ignore the error but cannot prevent the sheet from being created. Another way would be to delete the newly created sheet inside the `If - End If` code. Also since you are running this code from Excel, you don't need to prefix your objects with `Excel.` as in `Excel.Range`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Thanks for the suggestions.  I agree with the specific ones about adding and naming the new sheet.  In regards to including the object type in variable declaration, that's something I always do, even when it's an Excel object called from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Doug, this is great. Slight mod to avoid having to re-name the range:

```
    'select list range before running procedure
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In Selection
    With wbToAddSheetsTo
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for my needs:

```
Sub C_CreateEmptySheets()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Distribution Tab A2 down

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Distribution").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with sheets
     .add.name="SheetA"
     .add.name="SheetB"
     .add.name="Sheetc"
end with
```